# SQL Pivot (what am I doing wrong)

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, dynamic

I have a table that looks as follows and want to pivot it

```
Acct_ID Dec_DT                  Dec_rsn
1       2013-04-01 00:00:00.000 k
1       2013-01-01 00:00:00.000 x
1       2013-01-02 00:00:00.000 y
1       2013-10-02 00:00:00.000 z
2       2013-01-01 00:00:00.000 x
2       2013-01-01 00:00:00.000 y
2       2013-11-01 00:00:00.000 x
3       2013-12-01 00:00:00.000 z
4       2013-01-01 00:00:00.000 z
5       2013-11-01 00:00:00.000 y
5       2013-02-01 00:00:00.000 z
6       2013-03-01 00:00:00.000 x
1       2013-05-21 00:00:00.000 x
```

I have the following code but ist not working right....

```
DECLARE 
    @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @query  AS NVARCHAR(MAX)


SET @cols =
STUFF((SELECT distinct ',' + QUOTENAME(ROW_NUMBER()OVER(PARTITION BY ACCT_ID ORDER BY Dec_dt DESC)) as DecRsn
            FROM #test  c
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
        ,1,1,'')
set @query = 'Select Acct_ID, ' + @cols + ' from 
    (
        SELECT  
          Acct_ID, 
          Dec_DT, 
          Dec_rsn
        from #test

     )x

    pivot
    (
      max(Dec_DT)
    for Dec_rsn in (' + @cols + ')
    )p '

execute(@query)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
declare @stmt nvarchar(max)

select @stmt = isnull(@stmt + ', ', '') + Dec_rsn
from (select distinct Dec_rsn from Table1) as a

select @stmt = '
    select Acct_ID, ' + @stmt + '
    from Table1 as x
    pivot (
        max(Dec_DT) for Dec_rsn in (' + @stmt + ')
    )  as p'

exec sp_executesql @stmt = @stmt
```

**<kbd>[sql fiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/67cf7/2)</kbd>**

#### update

```
declare @stmt nvarchar(max)

select @stmt = isnull(@stmt + ', ', '') + Dec_rsn
from (select distinct 'Dec_rsn' + cast(dense_rank() over(order by Dec_rsn) as nvarchar(max)) as Dec_rsn from Table1) as a

select @stmt = '
    select Acct_ID, ' + @stmt + '
    from (
        select
            Acct_ID, Dec_DT, 
            ''Dec_rsn'' + cast(dense_rank() over(order by Dec_rsn) as nvarchar(max)) as Dec_rsn
        from Table1
    ) as a
    pivot (
        max(Dec_DT) for Dec_rsn in (' + @stmt + ')
    ) as p'

exec sp_executesql @stmt = @stmt
```

**<kbd>[sql fiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/67cf7/7)</kbd>**

#### update 2

```
declare @stmt nvarchar(max)

select @stmt = isnull(@stmt + ', ', '') + Dec_rsn
from (select distinct 'Dec_rsn' + cast(row_number() over(partition by Acct_ID order by Dec_DT) as nvarchar(max)) as Dec_rsn from Table1) as a

select @stmt = '
    select Acct_ID, ' + @stmt + '
    from (
        select
            Acct_ID, Dec_rsn, 
            ''Dec_rsn'' + cast(row_number() over(partition by Acct_ID order by Dec_DT) as nvarchar(max)) as rn
        from Table1
    ) as a
    pivot (
        max(Dec_rsn) for rn in (' + @stmt + ')
    ) as p'

exec sp_executesql @stmt = @stmt
```

**<kbd>[sql fiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/67cf7/10)</kbd>**

Comment: Thank you very much for this response, however I need to tweek it alittle instead of the headings being K X Y Z, I would like the headings to be Dec_rsn1, Dec_rsn2,Dec_rsn3,Dec_rsn4 etc and instead of the dates to have the Dec_rsn

Comment: @user3059409 it's some kind of trials and errors? please add desired output to your question.

Comment: thank you so much for the update, it worked but there was one thing missing, instead of the dates being populated in the in the rows, I would like to have the K X Y Z.

Also since these are decisions and the headings are DEC_RSN1 etc , I would like the (for example acct_id 2 to have the 1st and 2nd  DEC_RSN filed instead of having the 1st column blank)  ...

Comment: This is my desired output
ACCT_ID DEC_RSN1 DEC_RSN2 DEC_RSN3 DEC_RSN4
1 K X X Z
2 X X Y 
3 Z   
4 Z   
5 Y Z  
6 X

Comment: please see my question inthe following link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20388763/issues-with-my-sql-pivoting

Answer (score 1):

use this below query to solve your problem:

```
DECLARE 
    @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @query  AS NVARCHAR(MAX)

SET @cols =
STUFF((SELECT distinct ',' + QUOTENAME(ROW_NUMBER()OVER(PARTITION BY Acct_ID ORDER BY Dec_dt DESC)) as DecRsn
            FROM tbl  c
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
        ,1,1,'')

set @query = 'Select Dec_rsn,' + @cols + ' from 
    (
        SELECT  
          Acct_ID, 
          Dec_DT, 
          Dec_rsn
        from #test) x
    pivot
    (
      max(Dec_DT)
    for Acct_ID in (' + @cols + ')
    )p '

 print @query

 execute(@query)
```